# Responsive data merge in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I'm using InDesign's Data Merge feature for the first time and am wondering if there is anyway for the text being input into InDesign from a .csv file can be responsive in size. For example, if the text is only a few words it will increase in size to fill the text box it's in, or if the text is long it will decrease in size as to not flow outside the box. I haven't been able to confirm whether or not this is possible — any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've gotten quite close with scripts such as this one: http://in-tools.com/article/scripts-blog/fun-with-text-fitting-in-indesign/. Although unfortunately they can't treat each data merge entry individually, and only style the data merge variable itself (i.e. <<Tag>>).

Comment: This technique also comes close, but doesn't appear to work (at least from what I can tell) for larger text counts: http://colecandoo.com/2012/02/18/square-pegs-now-fit-into-round-holes/.